# db.collection.find() is not working with QUERY

Tags: database, collections, find

`db.collection.find( )` with  **query** is not working

> db.My_First_Collection.find() 
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5860a2d2487cb401d97af151"), "UserName" : "America", "Password" : "Trump", "UserId" : 1, "CreationDate" : "Mon Dec 26 2016 10:25:46 GMT+0530(India Standard Time)" } 
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("5860a2d2487cb401d97af152"), "UserName" : "NewArk", "Password" : "Obama", "UserId" : 2, "CreationDate" : "Mon Dec 26 2016 10:25:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" }
>
> db.My_First_Collection.find( { query: { "UserName" : "NewArk" } } )
>
> db.My_First_Collection.find(  query: { "UserName" : "NewArk" }  ) 
>   2016-12-26T10:34:58.033+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):1:35

What is wrong with syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.My_First_Collection.find({ "UserName" : "NewArk" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't inserted any objects when used

```
db.collection.find(){} // wrong query
```

use insert() to insert your data

```
db.My_First_Collection.insert( [ //[] used to insert multiple objects
   { 
     "_id" : ObjectId("5860a2d2487cb401d97af151"), 
     "UserName" : "America",
     "Password" : "Trump", 
     "UserId" : 1, 
     "CreationDate" : "Mon Dec 26 2016 10:25:46 GMT+0530(India Standard Time)" 
   } , //comma between objects 
   { 
     "_id" : ObjectId("5860a2d2487cb401d97af152"), 
     "UserName" : "NewArk", 
     "Password" : "Obama",
     "UserId" : 2, 
     "CreationDate" : "Mon Dec 26 2016 10:25:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" 
   } 
])
```